# Appearance Menus Screen - menu item drop down menu not functioning

Tags: menus, admin

According to WP, there should be options to remove/edit each menu item on a menu under appearance, but this option isn't showing up for me in Chrome or Firefox. I have administrator control of the site and not sure why this isn't working. Suggestions?

"Each Menu Item has a configuration arrow on the right side of the Menu Item title, that when clicked opens the configuration box. Click the arrow a second time closed the configuration box. If you don't see Link Target, CSS Classes, Link Relationship (XFN), and Description, then under Screen Options make sure those boxes are checked to expose them here."